# When I run google audit for checking my website getting error DevTools Error: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT

Tags: network-protocols, url-scheme

When I run google audit for checking my website getting error
DevTools Error: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT

Initial URL: https://cavrelli.com/category/science/? 
epc_purge_all=1&epc_purge_single=1
Chrome Version: 73.0.3683.86
Error Message: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT
Stack Trace:

LHError: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT at eval (chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@f9b0bec6063ea50ce2b71f5b9abbae7beee319a6/audits2_worker/audits2_worker_module.js:1027:210)

Comment: try us Edge dev, if still stuck at PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT

Answer (score 1):

Try using incognito or disable all other extensions on chrome

More about it here:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/9331